Verification of R. Dixon's bound/free split prediction
In his book, 'Ergativity', R. Dixon makes a prediction on page 95:

if there is a split between bound and free forms, the former will
follow an accusative pattern, the latter - an ergative pattern.

The basis for the prediction is the Nominal Hierarchy wherein personal pronouns occupy the left-hand side of it which reflects the fact that they are more likely to follow accusativity when there is a split.
I have not found any data pertaining to the matter in question on WALS. So my question is:
Is there a language that has the kind of split opposite to what Dixon's prediction leads us to expect?
Thank you!

Shouldn't your first 'latter' should be 'former'

@GastonÜmlaut, yes, it shoud

What exactly does he mean by “a split between bound and free forms” here? Is he talking about standalone pronouns vs personal inflectional affixes?

@JanusBahsJacquet, Bound forms - personal affixes, free forms - nouns (pronouns are not necessarily included as there may be a split between nouns and pronouns). I googled a bit and found out a language called Guajajara. It has a split within verbal agreement (among other observable splits elsewhere).

Oh, that makes more sense – I read the entire question as being limited to only pronouns and couldn’t quite grasp the meaning.
